# Pass variable as Ref name

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to extract ref name from hash and pass it to `scrollIntoView` without case/switch.

Suggestions how achieve this simple/best way?

[Full working  code with comments here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-gareth-mhm4f?file=/src/App.js:284-730)

Stupid but works

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.location.hash) {
      switch (props.location.hash.slice(1)) {
        case "targetOne":
          return targetOne.current.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth"
          });
        case "targetTwo":
          return targetTwo.current.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth"
          });
        default:
          return null;
      }
    }
  }, [props.location.hash]);
```

The "idea"

```
useEffect(() => {
if (props.location.hash) {
 props.location.hash.slice(1).current.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: "smooth"
  });
 }
  }, [props.location.hash]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store all the scrollable refs in one `useRef` which contains an object:

```
const scrollRefs = useRef({});
```

Pass a functional ref setter to the elements which need to be scrollable. Example:

```
<div ref={el => scrollRefs.current["targetOne"] = el}>
    <h2>Target One box</h2>
    ....
</div>
```

Now you can look up the elements by hash name in the ref object:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (props.location.hash) {
    const hash = props.location.hash.slice(1);
    const ref = scrollRefs.current[hash];
    ref && ref.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  }
}, [props.location.hash]);
```

Comment: Thank you, im trying this approach but with some mistakes. Thanks a lot!